# How to add shortcode with filters form in widget but result of this form show on content page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I add shortcode in such way:

```
add_shortcode( 'NAME', array( $shortcode, 'add_shortcode' ) );
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

This shortcode display html form with filters.
This shortcode I use(add) in widjet, but the result of this form I want to display on content page.
So I click submit the form and the result displays on content page.
How can I do this in best way?

I will be glad of any help.

Comment: Why all the down votes - just because the question is difficult, or seems unlikely to answer, or is structured incorrectly. Why do those who think they know more than others down vote questions from less experienced, or from those who's primary language is not english?  People come to places like StackOverflow to ask questions - there is no wrong questions - just those with unfounded hubris that down vote because they feel superior to others.  If you think you're better, then SOF is no place for your vanity.

Comment: Louys, I am agree with you, thx.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit difficult to do in a eloquent manner.  The reason is that most WP templates generate the content before they generate the widgets - in the majority of templates the content is generated in files like `content-page.php` and the widgets are generated from files like `sidebar.php`.

Your best bet is to use some jQuery to inject HTML after the fact.  For example, in the content you can generate an empty tag like this:

```
<div id="post-load"></div>
```

and then have your widget call something like this:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#post-load").html('your html goes here');
  });
</script>
```

I know this does not answer your question more completely, but it's difficult to assume what your starting point is.

Comment: @user6403246: Mark it as "accepted" answer *(green check mark)*, if this solved your issue. ;)

Comment: It is not solved my issues, I take another way:) does not matter thanks for answers. 
If you can help me with another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612905/how-run-shortcode-before-loading-header-php-in-wordpress

Comment: I don't use jquery, I use this
 function add_post_content( $content ) {
  $result  = new Result();
  $content = $result->my_function(); /* return result which I put in content */

  return $content;
 }

 add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_post_content' );