# How run shortcode before loading header.php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, shortcode

guys. I have some situation when my shortcode don't work correctly, if I add shortcode in header, because first of all load header.php and only after that load my shortcode. 
How can I run shortcode before loading header.php ?
I try to use hoocks, but not find solution.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run your code just before your `header.php` is loaded you can use the `get_header` hook:

```
function run_before_header( $name ) {
    do_shortcode...
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'run_before_header' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a Widget in the Backend of your WP-Admin and the Widget is called: "my_specials" and you want to display this Widget in the header, right? OK; try doing something like this within the header.php:

```
    <?php
        // FILENME: header.php

        ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar('my_specials');
        $mySpecials   = ob_get_clean();

        // NOW YOU HAVE THE CONTENT OF THE 'my_specials' WIDGET IN THAT VARIABLE.
        // ANY YOU CAN NOW ECHO IT AT THE SECTION OF YOUR CHOOSING LIKE SO:
        echo $mySpecials
```

It is imagined that this is what you meant and also hoped that this might help a bit, though...

Good-Luck to you, Mate...

Comment: Thanks, I know about this) But I wan't to add shortcode in header.php in such way. I created shortcode using plugin and added my shortcode in header widget in admin panel.

Comment: @user6403246  What about the updated version of the code?

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem using hook get_header.